# Migrating CognitoIdentityCredentials to modular AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have not been able to convert this code block to modular AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3). How could I migrate this to v3 ?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });
var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `AWS.config` won't work based on [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) section on **Configuration**

> In v3, there is no longer a global configuration managed by the SDK. Configuration must be passed to each service client that is instantiated.

You can use `fromCognitoIdentity()` from module [@aws-sdk/credential-providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.html) to pass credentials to each service client (or save those credentials in a variable and share across clients).

```
const client = new FooClient({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: fromCognitoIdentity({
    identityId: env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
  }),
});
```